# Collapsing data frame rows

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, aggregate

I have a data frame, a:

```
> a
  GID         1          2           3          4           5          6           7          8          9          10
1   A 0.2616485 -0.1521032 -0.01281316 0.05029606 -0.01940657  0.1624178  0.14714370 0.08642461 -0.1191233 -0.01845165
2   A 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000 0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
3   B 0.1107565  0.1632392 -0.08760204 0.04475998 -0.10835387 -0.0827655 -0.08058794 0.15288650 -0.1120538 -0.02297707
4   B 0.0000000  0.0000000  0.00000000 0.00000000  0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000 0.00000000  0.0000000  0.00000000
```

And I'm looking for a way to get a new data frame (b) which sums the rows of data frame a  by the GID column in a:

```
> b
  GID         1          2           3          4           5          6           7          8          9          10
1   A 0.2616485 -0.1521032 -0.01281316 0.05029606 -0.01940657  0.1624178  0.14714370 0.08642461 -0.1191233 -0.01845165
3   B 0.1107565  0.1632392 -0.08760204 0.04475998 -0.10835387 -0.0827655 -0.08058794 0.15288650 -0.1120538 -0.02297707
```

Preferably using a base solution.

Answer (score 4):

Use `aggregate`:

```
aggregate(.~GID,data=dat,sum)
```

**EDIT**

For better performance, you can try `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(dat)

DT[,lapply(.SD,sum),by='GID']
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. Obviously this works but it seems very inefficient for the dimensions of my data.frame (several rows by 100000 columns). Is there anything faster?